# Grouped TableView last cell border

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I can't get rid of last cell shadow/border. Just look at the image and you'll understand what I am talking about

[image]

Anyone knows how to get rid of it? I have clear background for cell and for tableview, yet the border below still apears.

Thank you.

Comment: How you are clearing background for cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should remove the white bottom border on each of the `UITableView` section:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

Comment: This sure did help. Thank you! I'll be sure to know this next time.